# Swift Realm exception

Tags: ios, swift, realm

On my homeViewController I have a tableView with cells.
Cells are filled with data from Realm database.
Each cell can be deleted.
After deleting a cell everything is fine.
When I go to another viewController, and then go back again to Home, the app crashes, reason :

> "Object has been deleted or invalidated."

Any ideas? Reload data and similar stuff doesn't help.
I am new in Realm stuff.

This is where I read my data from Realm to table

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //tableView.reloadData()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let result = realm.objects(CardsetTable.self)
    for r in result {
        self.cardsets.append(r)
    }
    for x in cardsets{
        self.titles.append(x)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And this is where I delete cell and Realm data :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let newSet = CardsetTable()
        newSet.cards = self.titles[indexPath.row].cards
        newSet.size = self.titles[indexPath.row].size
        newSet.title = self.titles[indexPath.row].title
        newSet.id = self.titles[indexPath.row].id
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(realm.objects(CardsetTable.self).filter("title=%@",titles[indexPath.row].title))
        }
        titles.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on topic.

Comment: Might not be the cause of your problem, but it is definitely an issue: you should move the all code, including the `beginUpdates...` inside the `if` statement. Also, you should never call `reloadData` inside a `beginUpdates`...`endUpdates` block. `reloadData` reloads the whole tableview, which you don't want, since by calling `beginUpdates` you tell iOS that you are doing manual updates on the table view (which you actually do, using `deleteRows`).

Comment: What is the type of titles array? is it CardSetTable? What's the point of newSet?

Comment: No point of newSet... Forgot to delete it. Type of titles is CardsetTable, yes.

Comment: One possible issue is every time you navigate back to the viewController, you're populating your tableView datasource with additional info. So the first time you view the controller, 3 objects are loaded from Realm and put into the dataSource array. Then navigate away from the viewContoller and back (assuming the viewController is not deallocated) it calls that function again and loads 3 more objects on top of the 3 already loaded. Keep in mind with `viewWillAppear`, because you might be going back and forth between views, it will be called every time the view is about to appear on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, viewWillAppear was not a good idea. Now I moved everything from viewWillAppear into viewDidLoad. App doesn't crash. But problem is refreshing data. I have a secondViewController where I download data from webServer. When I go from HomeVC to SecondVC and choose what data to download, it downloads in database properly. But when I go back to the HomeVC where my data from DB is displayed, no new data is displayed, but with viewDidLoad it was displayed on HomeVC. Any ideas how to refresh, update my HomeVC right after downloading in SecondVC? @Jay

Comment: What does *it downloads in database properly* mean? Also, you're describing a situation with your code but there's no code that reflects what you're doing so we won't be able to assist. This sounds like a different issue then you originally posted so you may want to consider closing or deleting this question and ask a new question about the new issue. Be sure to include code examples so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry @Jay , I fixed everything, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to improve here.
In the viewWillAppear, you are fetching the results from realm and doing the same again in your `editingStyle:` method which is unnecessary.

```
let result = realm.objects(CardsetTable.self)
```

You are adding the results to an array self.cardsets, which is not needed. You can use the `result` as an array and access its elements based on index.

There is a possibility that you are unnecessarily adding realm elements in `viewWillAppear`, since `viewWillAppear` might get called many times, you need to take care of adding realm elements to an array as they get duplicated if you don't remove previous added elements.

Coming to editingStyle method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let newSet = CardsetTable()
        newSet.cards = self.titles[indexPath.row].cards
        newSet.size = self.titles[indexPath.row].size
        newSet.title = self.titles[indexPath.row].title
        newSet.id = self.titles[indexPath.row].id
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(realm.objects(CardsetTable.self).filter("title=%@",titles[indexPath.row].title))
        }
        titles.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

I'm not actually sure why you create a new Realm object `let newSet = CardsetTable()` and don't use it.

At this line :

```
realm.delete(realm.objects(CardsetTable.self).filter("title=%@",titles[indexPath.row].title))
```

you are re-fetching items from your realm db. This is also unnecessary. You could call the filter method on your prefetched realm array `self.cardsets`

There are many possibilities for the error. It says the object you are trying to delete is already deleted or no longer valid.

I see two possible reasons:

1 - one of the realm object returned by realm.objects(CardsetTable.self) is already deleted

2 -  titles[indexPath.row] is returning a realm object, then accessing .title will cause error as titles[indexPath.row] already deleted from db.

you can always validate the object is invalidated or not

```
  if (!rlmObj.isInvalidated){
        // delete
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your big desire to help, but deleting and viewWillApear are not problem anymore and my app doesn't crash. Can you please read my last comment in comment section under my Answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As dávid-pásztor said, you should not call reloadData from inside a beginUpdates operation.

You're crash maybe related to code you have not shown here.  How are you displaying table cells and using the realm objects stored in card sets and titles.  This is likely the cause of the crash, since youre view controller is retaining realm objects that have been deleted from realm.

you'll need to update your card sets and titles when items are deleted from realm.

side note, why are you storing the same realm objects in two different arrays?

Comment: I moved reloadData as David said but it still crashes.
I am storing in 2 diff. arrays to make my searchBar easier.

Comment: @faris97. you'll need to update those arrays immediately after deleting from realm in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle) before running beginUpdates.  Once a object is deleted from realm, any properties that maybe retaining that object need to be updated.

Comment: thanks for help, but deleting is not problem anymore and my app doesn't crash. Can you please read my last comment in comment section under my Answer? Thanks.